# JavaScript Executor in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to use JavaScript for my script.

I have created an `object` of `JavaScriptExecutor`, but `executeScript()` method is not present. It shows error when I use `executeScript()` method.

This is the code I have used:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;


public class GetDomain_JS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://only-testing-blog.blogspot.in/2013/11/new-test.html");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());

        JavaScriptExecutor js=(JavaScriptExecutor) driver;

        String domain_name=(String) js.executeScript("return document.domain");

                System.out.println(doamin_name);

    }
}
```

Comment: I should use JavascriptExecutor instead of JavaScriptExecutor.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It works for me; you had a mistake on `JavaScriptExecutor` with upper case `S`.  Instead, you should have `javascriptExecutor` with lower case `s`.

Try this code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;


public class GetDomain_JS {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://only-testing-blog.blogspot.in/2013/11/new-test.html");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());

    JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor) driver;

    String domain_name=(String) js.executeScript("return document.domain");

            System.out.println(domain_name);

}
}
```

This works for me!! Please thumps up if it does for you!

Comment: What is the difference? Corrected typo in `System.out.println(doamin_name);`?

Comment: Its works now, The mistake is: I have created instance of JavaScriptExecutor, JavascriptExecutor (lowercase S) is the correct one.

Comment: JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor) driver;

I didn't understand this line, JavascriptExecutor is an interface, so we are casting driver object to JavascriptExecutor??

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you have imported the correct package.

Expected package for working with Java Script:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
```

Try this package. This should solve your error.

Answer (score 1):

## Explanation:

> Add latest jar (I'm using 3.0 beta selenium jar). Import Javascript library package. Take web driver object by casting to JavascriptExecutor and run whatever java script you want to run.

## Code:

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.JavascriptLibrary;
Object ob = ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver()).executeScript("return document.domain").toString();
System.out.println(ob);
```

Comment: Your answer certainly is worth a little explanation. This would add searchable content, so that other users will find it and benefit from our work.

Comment: Agreed, i thought there are many answers so all have little idea what code says. Added some more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can return an Object from executeScript. Later you can get the text out of it.

```
Object domain_name = js.executeScript("return document.domain");

System.out.println(domain_name.toString());
```

In this way, you can return values of any type and not just string.