# I want an action to be performed not get any object value or any other.

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to execute a command which deletes an element from the canvas in selenium . The command is this "  window.app.design.internalLayer().find('.deletebutton').fire('click')] " . this will find the particular image and delete it. and Its not working . When I open consle and type the above command it deletes an existing image I have . I have no object/values to return

Thanks in advance,
Sampath

Comment: Share HTML code of your page.

Comment: You want to look at a JavascriptExecutor, check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098520/javascript-executor-in-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score -1):

Following code will execute javascript and scroll down the window

```
//create the JavascriptExecutor using the driver object
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

//pass the javascript code that u want to execute
js.executeScript("javascript:window.scrollBy(250,350)");
```