# JavascriptExecutor cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am getting following error

```
JavascriptExecutor cannot be resolved to a type
```

while i am using the following

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", webelement);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098520/javascript-executor-in-selenium-webdriver check this link sunitha

Comment: Make sure you have `import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;`.Also clean & compile the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to import JavascriptExecuter class from java API. then your error will be rectified.

hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. it is working fine with above import statement

Answer (score 1):

Add the below import

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
```

and it'll fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try below :-

```
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", webelement));
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing a boolean statement in your js-snippet. Try

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", webelement);
```