# looking for option to check if page fully loaded with all elements in java for selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am looking for function in **Java** +selenium where I can check or verify if page is fully loaded. I saw `onLoad()` of JS but nothing on java, is there is something for JAVA?

also I saw these:

```
WebDriver driver = new AnyDriverYouWant();
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
   ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("yourScript();");
} else {
   throw new IllegalStateException("This driver does not support JavaScript!");
}
```

but again JS and need to write script in JS
[How to use JavaScript with Selenium WebDriver Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430773/how-to-use-javascript-with-selenium-webdriver-java)

**update** - also can try these solution too:
`void waitForLoad(WebDriver driver) { 
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) wd -> ((JavascriptExecutor) wd).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete")); }`

from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15124562/12115696

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to determine if a page is fully loaded, you will need to identify which WebElements on the page indicate a loading status. For example, if there is a load mask of some type, you will want to wait until the load mask is hidden to verify that the page is fully loaded.

Here's a simple "Wait until loaded" function that utilizes the `ExpectedConditions` class:

Given the following HTML for a load mask:

```
<div id='load-mask' style='display: block'/>
```

You can use the following code to wait until the load mask is hidden:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.Id("load-mask")));
```

Edit -- added a JavaScript-only wait function, as requested by the asker:

```
 wait.until(driver=> ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
```

This checks the `document.readyState` attribute in JavaScript, and completes the wait once `readyState` is set to `complete`.

Comment: Thank you, the solution is well known and it's very good but these is first of all in JS and i need in Java (yes i know its very simmilar) but rather than these, i need solution that it won't be depend on a particular element cause i have no such element, and these is the question if there is something like these? any kind of verification that the page is fully loaded on all requests for example

Comment: Thank you for the extra details. I have added something to my answer that only checks the JavaScript on the page instead of looking for any elements.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, but these is working in JS enviroment isn't it? i'm writing in Java, can these solution be edited for Java?

Comment: This is Java code that I posted. You can use a Selenium WebDriver to execute JavaScript on the page and check if it is loaded.

Comment: strange, i tried even to use these before :

    `JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;`

but still i get error on that line that:

    `JavaScriptExecutor cannot be resolved to a type`

Comment: you have to import JavascriptExecuter class from java API: `import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;` Make sure the s in Javascript is lowercase too.

Comment: I'm not sure how to help, I can only direct you to people with similar issue: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098520/javascript-executor-in-selenium-webdriver/24101994

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45952444/javascriptexecutor-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type

Comment: when its with small s so the error is
`Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to WebDriver`
and on the until the error is `The method until(Function<? super WebDriver,V>) in the type FluentWait<WebDriver> is not applicable for the arguments (WebDriver)`

Comment: This may help https://softwaretestingboard.com/q2a/1907/function-webdriver-fluentwait-webdriver-applicable-arguments#axzz60ZcNcLmZ

Comment: If you continue having issues with this error message, you might have better luck creating a separate question, since the error message has deviated from the original problem you were trying to solve.

Comment: my Guava library is version 25 (only one) and my JDK is version 8, i'm working with Maven.
im not sure from where it is cause for example `JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
` these is working

Comment: The issue is not with the `JavascriptExecutor` anymore, it is the `wait.until` keyword. a few solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421148/wait-untilexpectedconditions-doesnt-work-any-more-in-selenium

Comment: so i added the new dependency and actualy got the new wait `public <V> V until(Function<? super T, V> isTrue) {}`  even put it as the first dependency but still the same, my question now is how the scrolling with the JS is working like no problem?

Comment: these also looks working `void waitForLoad(WebDriver driver) {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) wd ->
            ((JavascriptExecutor) wd).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
}`
from here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15124562/12115696)

Comment: that looks correct, it's functionally the same as what I posted so if it compiles then you should use that.

Comment: still your solution will help, so a V on it's was