# Selenium Java Test Wait for Redirect to Finish

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver

Supposed I wanted to test my LoginPage functionality.  SO if I enter the correct username and password then I am redirected into the welcomepage.jsp .

I used container managed security so there are some j_security_check that you will see in the URL.

```
Feature: MyApp Login Feature
  Validate MyApp Login Features

  Scenario Outline: User logs to MyApp
    Given I navigate to MyApp login page
    And I enter <username> and <password>
    And I click on login button
    Then user entered correct username and password then they should be redirected to the proper <url>

    Examples: 
      | username     | password              | url                  |
      | correctuser  | correctpassword       | welcome.jsp          |
```

My problem is how to handle the 302 redirect.
If I looked at my network tab in my browser I am seeing below sequence

1. POST j_security_check
2. GET welcome.jsp

   ```
   @Then("^Then user entered correct username and password then they should be redirected to the proper ([^\"]*)$")
   public void user_should_be_redirected_to_the_proper(String expectedURL) throws Throwable {
       System.out.println("expectedURL :: " + expectedURL );
       if (driver.getCurrentUrl().contains(expectedURL)) {
           System.out.println("MyApp Test Pass");
       } else {
           System.out.println("MyApp Test Failed");
           Assert.fail("MyApp Test failed!");
       }
   }
   ```

I have seen some questions here that ask about this like 
[JavaScript Executor in Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098520/javascript-executor-in-selenium-webdriver)

But I think this isnt an AJAX Call were we are waiting for a DOM Ready

Answer (score 0):

Try using one of these `ExpectedConditions`, [urlMatches](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#urlMatches-java.lang.String-), [urlContains](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#urlContains-java.lang.String-), [urlToBe](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#urlToBe-java.lang.String-) before the assertions to wait for the redirect to complete.

Comment: Hi mate..my problem is how do you delay such test until the current url is already forwarded to welcome.jsp? The url changes and is redirected to a new welcome.jsp page. This isn't an ajax request where we are just waiting for the return value. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

@Grasshopper's Answer was in the right direction that you need to induce [WebDriverWait](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) inconjunction with [ExpectedConditions](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html). But as you would be asserting the `getCurrentUrl()` with the `expectedURL` instead of *urlMatches*, *urlContains* or *urlToBe* you need to use the [**`titleContains()`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#titleContains-java.lang.String-) method passing the argument of *Page Title* of the final *url*. The *ExpectedConditions* `titleContains()` which will return true when the title matches as per your *Application Title*. This inturn will ensure you that the final *url* have set in. You can use the following code block where I have assumed that the final *url* ending with **welcome.jsp** will have a *Page Title* as **Welcome - Mark Estrada - Home Page** :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
// other lines of code
@Then("^Then user entered correct username and password then they should be redirected to the proper ([^\"]*)$")
public void user_should_be_redirected_to_the_proper(String expectedURL) throws Throwable 
{
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("Welcome - Mark Estrada - Home Page"));
    System.out.println("expectedURL :: " + expectedURL );
    if (driver.getCurrentUrl().contains(expectedURL)) {
    System.out.println("MyApp Test Pass");
    } else {
    System.out.println("MyApp Test Failed");
    Assert.fail("MyApp Test failed!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wait until URL contains or matches some String:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;

WebDriverWait wait5s = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
wait5s.until(ExpectedConditions.urlContains("welcome.jsp"));
```

To wait to DOM is loaded better to wait to an element is clickable:

```
wait5s.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator);
```

or optionaly:

```
wait5s.until(ExpectedConditions.attributeToBe(locator, attribute, value);
```

In wrong credentials scenario just suround with `if/else`.