# How can I execute JS command using my chromedriver, inside a Java code?

Tags: javascript, java, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to ask you how can I scroll into a web page by using a JS command. Though, I want this JS command inside a Java code-block. For the above purpose let me tell you that I also use Selenium framework. Is it possible?

The purpose is to do so by using Selenium and Java. I don't care about the general usage of JavascriptExecutor. I want their combination for **SCROLL** functionality!

Comment: Browsers cannot natively run Java.  You will need some sort of Applet or Java plugin.  If you are talking in context of a Java based web app using JSP, then it's possible by using JavaScript in JSP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Executor in Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098520/javascript-executor-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: What do you mean by scroll? Scroll how much? Till the end of the page? Till a specific width? Till a specific element? Can you please specify this?

Comment: @SercanPaspal what you tagged above is not referring to scroll option. Though is referring to JavascriptExecutor. The last is just a part of this question, not the question itself. That's my personal opinion.

Comment: @Sid he said about Selenium so I guess that what he is looking for in my answer below. It's just a JavascriptExecutor interaction with Java.

Comment: @DimitriosV.Papadopoulos Totally understand it. The question was edited to add Selenium after my comment.

Comment: @Sid my bad. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to answer in detail with all the possible scroll options because it is not determined in the question. So I give you below a practical and a theoretical answer. The first one to finish your job and the second one to read theory for future usages because there are many options about this theme.

**Code sample:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor; // packet that you need to import

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); // driver creation

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; // giving to your driver the possibility to execute JS commands

js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(2000,1000)", ""); // scroll 2000 for x-coord and 1000 for y-coord
js.executeScript("window.scrollByPages(4)", ""); // scroll down the document by 4 pages
js.executeScript("window.scrollByPages(-4)", ""); // scroll up the document by 4 pages
js.executeScript("window.scrollByLines(10)", ""); // scroll down the document by 10 lines

WebElement toScrollElement = driver.findElement(By.XPATH_OR_ID_OR_OTHER("GIVEN_XPATH_OR_ID_OR_OTHER")); // locate the element you want to scroll into
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", toScrollElement); // scroll until the given element
```

**Theory documentation:**

I for one believe that the official documentation about this theme is included in the next links: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll) for scroll with **Window** options and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) for scrolling with **Element** options. I am sure that more documentation from other sources exists too. I just present you sources from which I took the information.

Also, JavascriptExecutor has a second option which is the `js.executeAsyncScript();`. You can also read the documentation of JavascriptExecutor itself from [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. thats waht i want

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly you are trying to scroll the page inside your selenium code. You can try something like this.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1000)"); //Scroll vertically down by 1000 pixels
```

Let us know how this works for you.